# \IfSubStr does not work when used as parameter of another macro

Tags: macros, conditionals, xstring

It seem that if macro `\IfSubStr` from package `xstring` is used as parameter it is not expanded like other macros are.

Here is minimal demonstration:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\copyArg}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \if#1W
    in then%
  \else
    in else%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
  \test{\copyArg{W}}
  \test{\IfSubStr{WKS}{W}{W}{N}}
\end{document}
```

I would expect this to print `in then in then`. Instead `\test{\IfSubStr{WKS}{W}{W}{N}}` behaves differently to previous macro and the output is `in then in else`. Why is that? How can I tweak my code or replace `\IfSubStr` by another macro so that I get expected result?

---

### Edit

Here I should explain what I need do. There is a macro like the `\test` macro shown in minimal example above. This macro has optional argument that works like switch - in very similar way it is shown in example above. If optional argument is `W` some actions are taken, it is unset or anything else then `W` some other actions are taken. It uses the same  `\if` `\else` condition that I have used in demo.

I am creating new macro that uses this existing macro. My macro has also first argument optional that may contain number of switches. One of them is that `W` switch. This switch is to be delegated existing macro. I thought I might code like this in my macro would do the trick `\theExistingMacro[\IfSubStr{#1}{W}{W}{}]{...}{...}` but it does not work. So how do I make it work?

---

### Edit 2

To clarify here is real life example.

There is a macro  like this (simplified code)

```
\newcommand{\addLabelAbove}[4][]{%
  \if#1W%
    \saveToNewBox{#2}{\vbox{\noindent#4\\*\noindent#3}}%
  \else%
    \saveToNewBox{#2}{\pbox{\textwidth}{\noindent#4\\*\noindent#3}}%
  \fi%
}%
```

I am creating new macro that calls different other macros one of which is `\addLabelAbove`

```
\newcommand{\block}[6][]{
  \uppercase{\IfSubStr{#1}}{A}{%then
    \uppercase{\IfSubStr{#1}}{L}{%then
      \doSomething{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}
    }{%else
      \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
      \addLabelAbove[\IfSubStr{#1}{W}{W}{}]{\theBoxCount}{#2}{#3}%
      \someMoreMacrosSkiped
    }%
  }{%else
    \someOtherUnimportantCommands           
  }%
}
```

The line `\addLabelAbove[\IfSubStr{#1}{W}{W}{}]{\theBoxCount}{#2}{#3}%` intends to call macro `\addLabelAbove` with switch `W` if there is `W` among switches given to macro `\block` or with without that switch if there is no `W` switch among switches given to `\block`. It does not work this way and I'd like to know how to make it work.

Comment: @cmhughes `\ifx` would compare `\IfSubStr` to `{`, which is surely *not* what's wanted. ;-)

Comment: Re the edit: is the optional argument expected to contain something like `AWK`? And in this case, should the macro take the `W` branch?

Comment: @egreg Yes, optional argument of macro I am creating is expected to contain something like `AWK` (multiple swithes). But the existing macro that I cannot alter is only expecting one switch - that is `W`. I'm not sure I understand your second question... The predefined macro (that I cannot alter) should get the `W` switch if and only if `W` was one of switches given to macro that I am creating.

Comment: The definition of `\addLabelAbove` is definitely *wrong*. If you call `\addLabelAbove[aa]{X}{Y}{Z}` it will follow the true branch and you'll have a `W` in the output. And if you call it with an empty optional argument you'll be in big trouble, because the first token of the expansion of `\saveToNewBox` will be eaten up.

Comment: @egreg I thought it might be wrong (because of all the trouble it is causeing me). I'm not supposed to alter this code - it is in another package but I can redefine `\addLabelAbove` command. What should the correct definition look like?

Comment: How to redefine it? It depends on how you are supposed to call it. As it is that macro will *not* work unless you *always* call it with a single letter optional argument.

Comment: @egreg The expected behaviour of `\addLabelAbove` is this: If optional argument is not set then the "else branch" is executed. If optional argument is set and it is string `W` then the "then branch" is executed. If optional argument is set and it contains more then one letter or it does not contain `W` then the "else branch" is executed.

Comment: Well, `\addLabelAbove` will *not* do that. However, the final code in my answer should fix this.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'd like to but it is kind of complicated... `\addLabelAbove` should create and save a hbox. Its #2 is name of the box to be saved, #3 argument takes main content of that hbox, while #4 argument is some additional content (label) that is placed one line above the main content. The `W` switch cause resulting hbox to contain nested vbox - which means it will occupy all the page width.
Macro `\block` creates and saves many hboxes containg same content but with different layout. `\addLabelAbove` creates and saves one of those layouts. User can control which layouts are included...

Comment: ...using optional switches. Also they can influence the some layouts by setting some other switches - one of them is `W` switch that influences layout created and stored by `\addLabelAbove` macro.

Answer (score 6):

The conditional `\if` compares the first two unexpandable tokens it finds after expanding the following tokens.

In the case of `\copyArg`, the expansion ends with `K`, so `\if` compares `K` to `K` and the test returns true.

In the second case, the first unexpandable token is `\let`, followed by `\reserved@d` whose value is not predictable. In any case the result of `\IfSubStr` is still very far from being computed to begin with.

It's not easy to understand what you want to do; surely, mixing these very differently behaving tests is not the right thing to try.

---

Let's assume your macro `\theMacro` takes an optional argument and a mandatory one; moreover it should call `\yesW` with the specified mandatory argument if `W` is a substring of the optional argument and `\noW` otherwise. Then this would do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\noW}[1]{Do something with #1 (no \texttt{W})}
\newcommand{\yesW}[1]{Do something else with #1 (\texttt{W} seen)}

\newcommand\theMacro[2][]{%
  \IfSubStr{#1}{W}
    {\yesW{#2}}
    {\noW{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\texttt{W} should not be seen: \theMacro{`hello'}

\texttt{W} should not be seen: \theMacro[ABC]{`hello'}

\texttt{W} should be seen: \theMacro[W]{`world'}

\texttt{W} should be seen: \theMacro[AWK]{`world'}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without a "real life" example it's hard to say more.

An alternative way similar to your `\test` macro would be

```
\newif\ifW
\newcommand{\theMacro}[1][]{%
   \IfSubStr{#1}{W}{\Wtrue}{\Wfalse}%
   \ifW
      <then code>
   \else
      <else code>
   \fi}
```

that is, you delegate the test to `\ifW` instead of trying directly with the given optional argument.

---

Now, assuming you need to use the (faulty) macro `\addLabelAbove`, you can do just like in the above suggestion:

```
\newif\ifW
\newcommand{\block}[6][]{%
  \uppercase{\IfSubStr{#1}}{A}{%then
    \uppercase{\IfSubStr{#1}}{L}{%then
      \doSomething{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}
    }{%else
      \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
      \IfSubStr{#1}{#}{\Wtrue}{\Wfalse}%
      \ifW
        \addLabelAbove[W]{\theBoxCount}{#2}{#3}%
      \else
        \addLabelAbove[\relax]{\theBoxCount}{#2}{#3}%
      \fi
      \someMoreMacrosSkiped
    }%
  }{%else
    \someOtherUnimportantCommands
  }%
}
```

The `\relax` in the "non W" case is meant to fix the problem with `\addLabelAbove`, where the `\if` will compare `\relax` to `W`, so following the "else" branch correctly.

Comment: I have added explanation of what I want to do as an edit to the original question. Please have a look on it.

Comment: @drasto I added something for you.

Comment: I see that my problem is hard to understand. I'll add real life example to my question. My problem is that instead of those 2 commands `noW` and `yesW` there is only one long and complicated macro that I have to use (otherwise I would introduce a lot of code duplication). That long macro is something like `\test` macro from my original question.

Comment: I have added "real life example" to the question, well a little simplified. I do not think I can explain it much better. Any ideas on how can I do this are welcome.