# Create a version of a theorem whose environment name is capitalised

Tags: macros, theorems, csname

I want to write a macro `\createTheorem` that creates two environments: a normal one and a "capitalised" one.

For example, `\createTheorem{defi}{Definition}` will create :

- an environment `\begin{defi}...\end{defi}`
- and an environment `\begin{Defi}...\end{Defi}`.

How would you do that?
I would like to know why my code doesn't work.

### My code

Here is what I have tried. It doesn't work, the error being

> Missing \endcsname inserted. 
> \protect  l.13
> \documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theoremForCounter}{theoremForCounter}

\newcommand{\createTheorem}[2]
{ 
 \def\nameNewTheoremCapitalized{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
 \newtheorem{#1}[theoremForCounter]{#2}
 \newtheorem{\nameNewTheoremCapitalized}[theoremForCounter]{#2}
}

\createTheorem{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}
This is a test.
\end{defi}

\begin{Defi}
This is a test.
\end{Defi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `MakeUppercase` is not expandable (case 2 of [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646000/250119)). And even if it were, it's usually desirable to expand the arguments before passing it to commands (although it isn't necessary in this case).

Comment: I've tried indeed to `\expandafter` but it didn't work. Thanks for your interest in my question.

Comment: Should the two environments behave the same?

Comment: @egreg No: `\begin/\end{Defi}` will have a thicker frame than `\begin/\end{defi}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what would the usage of this would be: having two environments `defi` and `Defi` that do exactly the same is useless and possibly confusing.

Anyway, you can use `\text_titlecase:n` (with a LaTeX released after March 2020).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % probably you wanted this one

\newcounter{counterForTheorem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \uppercasefirst #1
 {
  \str_uppercase:f { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
  \tl_tail:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\createTheorem}[2]{%
  \newtheorem{#1}[counterForTheorem]{#2}%
  \newtheorem{\uppercasefirst{#1}}[counterForTheorem]{#2}%
}

\createTheorem{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}
This is a test.
\end{defi}

\begin{Defi}
This is a test.
\end{Defi}

\end{document}
```

Alternative implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % probably you wanted this one

\newcounter{counterForTheorem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\createTheorem}[2]{%
  \newtheorem{#1}[counterForTheorem]{#2}%
  \begingroup
  \edef\temp@a{\@car#1\@nil}%
  \edef\temp@b{\@cdr#1\@nil}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\uppercase{\def\noexpand\temp@a{\temp@a}}}\x
  \edef\temp@a{\temp@a\temp@b}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\newtheorem\expandafter{\temp@a}[counterForTheorem]{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\createTheorem{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}
This is a test.
\end{defi}

\begin{Defi}
This is a test.
\end{Defi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the point of the `text` functions is that you don't use it for "programmatic" things. But yes `titlecase` is more concise in this case.

Comment: @user202729 Changed to use `\str_uppercase:f`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, `MakeUppercase` is not expandable. You can use expl3 functions `str_uppercase:f` instead which is expandable:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\createTheorem}[2]
{ 
 \def\nameNewTheoremCapitalized{\str_uppercase:f{\tl_head:n{#1}}\tl_tail:n{#1}}
 \newtheorem{#1}{#2}
 \exp_args:Nx\newtheorem{\nameNewTheoremCapitalized}{#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\createTheorem{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}
This is a test.
\end{defi}

\begin{Defi}
This is a test.
\end{Defi}

\end{document}
```

Remark:

- in pdflatex `\tl_head` will take the first byte of the name instead of the first character, so I don't know what happens if the first character is not a simple ASCII character.
- If the first character is not a lowercase character `newtheorem` will raise error because the two names are identical.
- Your macro definition has [spurious spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/250119). Not so with `\ExplSyntaxOn`.
- In this case the implementation of `newtheorem` happens to already expand the argument inside, so there's no need of expanding the argument before passing to it... nevertheless I'm not sure if this behavior the guaranteed... so I add `\exp_args:Nx` just in case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give a LaTeX solution? I've tried adding `\usepackage{expl3}` and compiling with LaTeX but it does not work.

Comment: @Colas `expl3` is a LaTeX solution and part of the kernel for the last two years. One could help you better if you added more information than "does not work".

Comment: My distribution is too old I think. I have to put `\usepackage{expl3}` but still there is an error: `Undefined control sequence.
\nameNewTheoremCapitalized ->\str_uppercase:f `. I'll try download a newer version of `expl3`.

Comment: @Colas don't only update to a newer version of `expl3` (that won't work, I'm afraid). Just update to a newer TeX Live version. Alternatively, put the following after `\ExplSyntaxOn`: `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_uppercase:n { f }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TeX primitive `\uppercase` directly, but this is still not expandable, so we have to trick a bit. `\createTheorem@a` is used to get the first character, and calls `\createTheorem@b` after the first character was already upper-cased, and puts the name back together.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\long\def\createTheorem@a#1#2\end
  {\uppercase{\createTheorem@b{#1}}{#2}}
\newcommand\createTheorem@b[2]{\newtheorem{#1#2}}
\newcommand{\createTheorem}[2]
{% 
  \newtheorem{#1}{#2}%
  \createTheorem@a#1\end{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\createTheorem{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}
This is a test.
\end{defi}

\begin{Defi}
This is a test.
\end{Defi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. I would to do the same trick with a command `\myCommand{}` which takes one argument. What would be the syntax to create a command `\myCommandWithCapital{}`? Thanks

Comment: @Colas Not sure what you mean -- nevertheless if the question is sufficiently different consider asking a new question instead. (by the way you might want to read the TeXbook to learn some TeX programming and understand this answer.)

Comment: @Colas, the solution is the same. Just use `\newtheorem{#1}[WHATEVER]{#2}` in `\createTheorem` and `\newtheorem{#1#2}[WHATEVER]` in `\createTheorem@b`.