# Numbers from command fed into a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

The following code does not compile with "pdflatex file.tex", and I am not sure how to fix it. The 9th line is the problem. Specifically \MV.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\MV{\foreach\item in {2}{3}}
\newcommand\YV{2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,0) node[below=3pt] {\MV}; % works
\draw (0,0) -- (2,\YV);            % works
\draw (0,0) -- (2,\MV);            % fails
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\foreach ...reach \let \pgffor@assign@before@code 
                                                  =\pgfutil@empty \let \pgff...
```

Comment: It fails with the same error using `\edef\foo{\MV}` outisde the tikzpicture.  My advice is, "Don't do that."

Comment: Expandability issues. Unfortunately TeX is complicated and the TeXbook is not free. Refer to [verbatim - Why can't I use <some macro> inside the argument of <some other macro>? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645995/250119) .

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand, this is not due to expandability, but to a misuse of `\foreach`.

Just try to replace your `\MV` by its definition: it makes nonsense in line 9. It works flawless in line 7 since the command is for the node content, not the position.

I slightly tweak your example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\MV{\foreach\item in {2,...,4}{\item+3}}
\newcommand\YV{2}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,0) node[below=3pt] {\MV}; % works
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,\YV);            % works
%    \draw (0,0) -- (2,\MV);           % fails
%    \draw (0,0) -- (2,\foreach\item in {2,...,4}{\item+3});  % fails
    \foreach \item in {2,...,4}{
      \draw (0,0) -- (2,\item) node[below=3pt] {\item};       % works
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]